# Custom CSS Form: How to achieve responsive underlined textarea?

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm looking to achieve an effect where, when typing in a form, the textarea grows as you type, and adds an underline for each line of text.

See the effect in GIF form here:
[image: textarea effect]

Can this be easily accomplished just by using CSS? How might I go about this?

Comment: I've created a rough JSFiddle here to get started:
http://jsfiddle.net/y467a/

Comment: `text-decoration:underline; line-height: 150%;` won't give you the spacing between the underline and the words but it's a start.

Comment: On top of the textarea @javinladish created for you in the JSFiddle if you add ```text-decoration: underline;``` like I did here it should help.http://jsfiddle.net/892eY/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the constant underlines by making a background image that has some blank space and an underline. Then set the image as background of your textarea and have it repeat. Lastly, set the `line-height` in CSS to be equal to the height of your background. The lines will now repeat along with the height of the text.

For the textarea resizing, you can use TrungDQ's answer or one of many libraries available through Google.

Comment: Where can you find TrungDQ's answer?

Comment: Right above/below mine. He answered your question as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by using a `<div contenteditable="true">` instead of `textarea`:

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] 
   feedback-input" id="comment" 
   placeholder="Start writing your message here..."></div>
```

CSS:

```
.feedback-input>div{
    padding: 2px 0;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.feedback-input>div:first-child{
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.feedback-input>div:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trungdq88/5fV8w/)

Adjust the CSS as you want.

Comment: is there a way to get the placeholder to still work?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  Just had to add [contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
}
in the CSS.